# Is this a predatory conference?

Tags: ethics, conference

https://www.pagesconferences.com/physics/

I was invited despite never communicating with anyone in the committee, the email was not marked as spam though.

Comment: "Exploring the Innovations and Modern Break Through in the field of Physics." Can't tell if it's predatory or not, but it doesn't seem to put much effort into proofreading.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a serious conference advertised where the venue is just "Brussels". What are you supposed to do, wander aimlessly around the city hoping to bump into other people that look like lost physicists?

Comment: I wonder if *email was not marked as spam* is a valid indicator. They want your money; this takes some effort.

Answer (score 7):

This conference has many hallmarks of predatory conferences.

1. Based on their [webpage](https://www.pagesconferences.com/), the company is reportedly "running" at least 4 conferences on the same day in the same city with vastly different topics.
2. Each reported attendee's biography is plagiarized from a top Google search result. To confirm, copy and paste the biography into Google.
3. The abstract submission process does not detail any form of peer review.
4. The image of the conference attendees is the same on each conference webpage.
5. The domain of the conference organizer is [registered](https://lookup.icann.org/lookup) to a proxy organization intended to obfuscate the true owner.
6. [Other sources](http://flakyc.blogspot.com/2020/12/pangea-global-events-is-dedicated-to.html) on the internet have questioned conferences held by this organization.